# `python manage.py migrate` command makes me frustrated

Tags: python, django

I got a problem when I used the command `django-admin startproject mysite`, it couldn't work but `python -m django startproject mysite` is ok.
There has been another problem in my `CneOs6.8`, when I enter `python manage.py migrate`, which would output:

> [root@localhost mysite]# python manage.py migrate

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-

packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 31, in <module>
    from 

pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

During 

handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent 

call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-

packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 33, in <module>
    from sqlite3 

import dbapi2 as Database
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    

from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    

from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the 

above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  

File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-

packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in 

execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-

packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup

()
  File "/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", 

line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 

108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 

202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  

File "/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in 

import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File 

"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen 

importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen 

importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen 

importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen 

importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen 

importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", 

line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, 

BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-

packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class 

AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-

packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class

('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 

325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", 

line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, 

connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 

33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, 

in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, 

in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in 

import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File 

"/usr/local/python3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-

packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 35, in <module>
    raise 

ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in 

that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading 

either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named 

'_sqlite3'
```

***who can tell me what happened? Thank you, a million times over. additionally I wanted you to know that I am new to programming.***

Comment: as far as i know python3 includes sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 is not installed.Try to install them

`$ pip install sqlite3 # or pysqlite2`

Answer (score 1):

try to install lib in your linux OS

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

then try

```
pip install pysqlite
```

Comment: Uh, I've tried but it still can't work. when I am trying to install libsqlite3-dev use yum, which back to me a message: No package libsqlite3-dev available